# Run R Script passing variables from Python

Tags: python, r

I have a process developed in R that I have to run from a Jupyter notebook in Python. I have to pass certain variables to the process and so far I have not succeeded.
I show you what I've tried so far. 
Thank you for your help!

```
import subprocess

var=1

subprocess.check_output('Rscript \"--args $var \" /home/User/My_code.R' ,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: What variables are you trying to pass?

Comment: Only "var" in this example.

Comment: You need to provide a list of arguments like `subprocess.check_output(['Rscript', '--args', '$var', '/home/User/My_code.R'] ,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`